# Rails change Paperclip content type to text/xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, file, paperclip

I create an xml file with:

```
    xml_device_path = "#{xml_device_description.get_file_path_without_name}#{title}.xml"

    File.open("#{xml_device_path}", 'w') do |f|
        f.puts(content.to_xml)
    end
```

to attach this file via paperclip to my model.

```
file = File.open("#{xml_device_path}")
xml_device_description.xml = file
file.close
```

The resulting file has the content type "application/xml" but I need the content type "text/xml".

Is it possible to set or to manipulate the content type of an file or during the file creation?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Files themselves _do not have a content type_.

Comment: Building on what @mudasobwa has said, the content type is being set by the http server when sending it to the client. Most likely because it has the `.xml` extension. This should be fixed by just using the `.html` extension instead. Or, when sending the file down, you should be able to explicitly set the content type.

Comment: Mh, ok. But directly after creating the file on the server it has the type "application/xml" without any sending via the http server to the client. The file stay on the server and will not send to the client... Where come the content type from when it will never sended to the client?

Comment: @Kumaro how did you get a mime type for that file?

Comment: @PooyanKhosravi After "xml_device_description.xml = file" adding the file with paperclip to my model I can see the mime type in the db column "xml_content_type". So maybe paperclip decides the mime type?

Comment: @Kumaro that's my guess. Now edit your question to clearly state you want to change mimetype of a paperclip object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem as follows:

```
#change paperclip file content type 
xml_device_description.xml.xml_content_type = "text/xml"

#save activeRecord
xml_description.save!
```

I just set a new content type to the paperclip column in the db...